Where is the gender field in UNICEF's MICS6 dataset?
I'm looking at MICS6 I have the fs.sav dataset but can't find a flag for gender of the child. I have age etc. And I'm struggling to find a good data dictionary.
https://mics.unicef.org/surveys
It seems to have a sex variable HL4, but I thought this was from the household survey, e.g. for the head of household. Is this field definitely for the child each row reports on?
BH3 Sex of child also exists in the bh.sav file but this field is in multiple languages, which need recoding.
